# How to use redis to improve response time with my nodejs api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

How to use redis to improve response time with my nodejs api? i am trying to use Redis to improve my response time
but when i use it it is taking longer than my normal api when i was not using Redis it was fetching
data in 52-58ms but when i use Redis it is taking longer its taking 60-66ms in response time how to fix this problem
i checked my location its all correct

How to improve response time?

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const redisClient = new Redis({
    port: 16545,
    host: 'redis-16545.c305.ap-south-1-1.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com',
    password: 'mypass',
});

router.get('/posts', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const cacheKey = `posts:${req.query.page || 1}`;
        const cacheTTL = 60;
        const cachedData = await redisClient.get(cacheKey);
        if (cachedData) {
            console.log('Data fetched from Redis cache');
            return res.json(JSON.parse(cachedData));
        }
        const page = Number(req.query.page) || 1;
        const limit = Number(req.query.limit) || 50;
        const skip = (page - 1) * limit;
        const result = await User.aggregate([
            { $project: { posts: 1 } },
            { $unwind: '$posts' },
            { $project: { postImage: '$posts.post', date: '$posts.date' } },
            { $sort: { date: -1 } },
            { $skip: skip },
            { $limit: limit },
        ]);
        await redisClient.set(cacheKey, JSON.stringify(result), 'EX', cacheTTL);
        console.log('Data fetched from MongoDB and cached in Redis');
        res.json(result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the action **JSON.parse** is taking more run time?..

Did you try to use **redis** npm package with the **latest version 4.6.5**?

**You can save in redis the value object as is without the need to stringify on set and parse on get**.

For example:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';
...
// for set:
await client.json.set(cacheKey, '$', cachedData);
...
// for get:
const cachedData = await client.json.get(cacheKey);
if (cachedData) {
    console.log('Data fetched from Redis cache');
    return res.json(cachedData);
}
...
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis

https://github.com/redis/node-redis/tree/d65a641b2db96c6d63a2a51c43e823aba8256e28/packages/json

Comment: Can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76002562/why-redis-i-am-getting-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading?

Comment: I tried doing these changes but the response time is mostly the same as any other solution in your mind?

Comment: How many documents there are in MongoDB? because if there are only 20 documents so there shouldn't be a major difference in the run time between MongoDB and Redis.

Comment: there are many  documents